# Error: Error endorsing chaincode: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Failed to init chaincode(handler not found for chaincode mycc:0)

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I'm trying to make the tutorial ["**Chaincode for Developers**"](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/chaincode4ade.html#) work. But at the section ["**Terminal 3 - Use the chaincode**"](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/chaincode4ade.html#terminal-3-use-the-chaincode) I'm stuck trying to run this command

> $ peer chaincode instantiate -n mycc -v 0 -c '{"Args":["a","10"]}' -C
>   myc

It exits with this error :

> Error: Error endorsing chaincode: rpc error: code = Unknown desc =
>   Failed to init chaincode(handler not found for chaincode mycc:0)

I've done some research but I don't know what to do. Could somebody please help me ?

Comment: which release are you running?

Comment: I'm running the "1.1.0-preview" release

Comment: having some issues myself... I think that the certificates may be expired... give me some time to work on this

Comment: still investigating...

Comment: Ahah still waiting

Answer (score 0):

This is solved.  There were three primary problems.

1. As Chris mentioned, the certs are expired.  In the future you can easily check a certificate's validity by parsing it.  For example `openssl x509 -in your_cert.pem -text`
2. The provided artifacts were not configured properly.  Namely, the configtx.yaml that the configtxgen utility consumed did not have the orderer address defined correctly.
3. Lastly, the documented command to start the chaincode used the wrong port for the peer address.  Should be 7052 not 7051.

I will push a fix for this shortly

Comment: Hi, alright. I'm waiting for your fix. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Hello I'm still waiting, when will you push the fix please? I can't finish the tutorial without this fix.

Comment: Hi Pierre.  Have you tried recently?  We refreshed the certs and updated the network artifacts.  Works as expected now

Comment: Still does not work https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48153365/erro-003-error-trying-to-connect-to-local-peer-context-deadline-exceeded