# ERRO 003 Error trying to connect to local peer: context deadline exceeded

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

Following my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47699785/error-error-endorsing-chaincode-rpc-error-code-unknown-desc-failed-to-ini). I'm still trying to make the tutorial "Chaincode for Developers" work. It still does not work :

[Terminal 2 - Build & start the chaincode](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/chaincode4ade.html#terminal-2-build-start-the-chaincode), getting this error when running chaincode :

> userChaincodeStreamGetter -> ERRO 003 Error trying to connect to local peer: context deadline exceeded

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Unfortunately not but I will eventually

Answer (score 1):

After coming across this issue, I checked which ports which were being used by "peer", and 
was surprised to see that the port in question, 7052, was not listed as a peer node port.

So, I updated to this command, i.e. changing port 7052 to 7051:

```
CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer:7052 CORE_CHAINCODE_ID_NAME=mycc:0 ./sacc
```

TO:

```
CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer:7051 CORE_CHAINCODE_ID_NAME=mycc:0 ./sacc
```

Following that change, startup seems to work correctly (although the behavior soon looks like a hung process, once the code was registered. Subsequent tutorial steps worked as expected.)

LOGS:

ORIGINAL (FAILURE):

```
root@8e77a5eef847:/opt/gopath/src/chaincode/sacc# CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer:7052 CORE_CHAINCODE_ID_NAME=mycc:0 ./sacc
```

> 2018-03-27 02:18:56.211 UTC [shim] SetupChaincodeLogging -> INFO 001 Chaincode log level not provided; defaulting to: INFO
>
> 2018-03-27 02:18:56.211 UTC [shim] SetupChaincodeLogging -> INFO 002 Chaincode (build level: ) starting up ...
>
> 2018-03-27 02:18:59.212 UTC [shim] userChaincodeStreamGetter -> ERRO 003 Error trying to connect to local peer: context deadline exceeded

CORRECTED (SUCCESS):

```
root@8e77a5eef847:/opt/gopath/src/chaincode/sacc# CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer:7051 CORE_CHAINCODE_ID_NAME=mycc:0 ./sacc
```

> 2018-03-27 02:54:22.858 UTC [shim] SetupChaincodeLogging -> INFO 001 Chaincode log level not provided; defaulting to: INFO
>
> 2018-03-27 02:54:22.858 UTC [shim] SetupChaincodeLogging -> INFO 002 Chaincode (build level: ) starting up ...

(process continues in background?)

Answer (score 0):

in that above example,
the tutorial seems to explain register new port 7052 for interacting chaincode, instead 7051.

so, when I try below code in chaincode container,

```
*CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer:7052 CORE_CHAINCODE_ID_NAME=mycc:0 ./chaincode_example02*
```

I can see below log which seems to be register new port 7052 instead existing port 7051.

> sending new addresses to cc: [{peer:7052 0  }]

and I also checked newly opened port 7052 in peer container as below.

```
*root@00fd2d4f4346:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer# netstat -anpt
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 172.19.0.3:7052         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1/peer
tcp        0      0 172.19.0.3:7052         172.19.0.5:57246        ESTABLISHED 1/peer
tcp6       0      0 :::7051                 :::*                    LISTEN      1/peer*
```